# I want to count Phaser game no of tile my charachter in which tile.?

Tags: phaser-framework

https://github.com/SafaErden/IcyTower
My game from this project please give me solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast solution ist, just count the score up, when a platform-collision occurs.

Changes needed in the Code are:

In the file `GameScene.js`:

[line 67](https://github.com/SafaErden/IcyTower/blob/db80a0fcfe1362c2ca2c898b237414405afa0ee6/src/Scenes/GameScene.js#L67): **Change**

```
   this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.platformGroup);
```

to this:

```
this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.platformGroup, (player, platform) =>{
    // just checks if the player is over the platform (can be optimized)
    if(player.y < platform.y){
        // set Score (for the the I just update the Text)
        scoreText.setText(`Score:${platform.name  * 10}`);   
    }
});
```

[line 76](https://github.com/SafaErden/IcyTower/blob/db80a0fcfe1362c2ca2c898b237414405afa0ee6/src/Scenes/GameScene.js#L76): **Add** after this line this code:

```
// here I'm using the name property (that is reserved for developers), to keep track of the Platform number
platform.name = gameOptions.platformCounter;
```

Since `gameOptions.platformCounter` seems to be counted up during the game, this can work. *(or you can create an other property, to use for counting the score/platform)*.

**Info:** setting the score like this has the charme, that the user loses points again, if he drops to a lower platform

**Side note:** you would have to delete the *lines 125 and 126* for this to work:

```
    score = updateScore(score);
    scoreText.setText(`Score:${score}`);
```

***Of Topic* Update:**

InCase of "wanting to change code in the update", I would use/create properties. for example: in case of the level up on score 100 I would alter the code to this:

```
this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.platformGroup, (player, platform) =>{
    if(player.y < platform.y){
        // set Score (for the the I just update the Text)
        score = platform.name  * 10
        scoreText.setText(`Score:${score}`);   
    }
});
```

Create a global variable `level` similar to `score`:

```
let level = 0;
```

And the somewhere in the `update` function *(not in the `for` loop)*, just add something like this:

```
// Just to be sure that the level count only goes up
if(parseInt(score / 100)> level) { 
    level++;
    // change background / music / ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks man my issue is resolved from your solution much appreciated

Comment: @ArslanArshad you accepted answer, And now the checkmark is removed. Is there something wrong with the answer?

Comment: Yes i face some issue due to this

Comment: after 10 tile i want to change level the changing level code in update() function but this not accessible in update function

Comment: @ArslanArshad the code presented is ofcourse only a, short solution for the original question (I can't review all the code and possible extensions). This said, you can set the `score` in the collision, and/or prevent `score` to decrease. and in the `update` function you can change the level if the `score` is bigger that 100 or so.

Comment: please take a look of code

Comment: @ArslanArshad I don't see the problem, in any case I updated my answer, with some more pointers/code. I hope this helps